# How do I check the end of Stream in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

fellow dart programmers.

I am reading in a file using Stream as below.

```dart
Stream<List<int>> stream = new File(filepath).openRead();
stream
    .transform(UTF8.decoder)
    .transform(const LineSpilitter())
    .listen((line){
        // TODO: check if this is the last line of the file
        var isLastLine;
    });
```

I want to check whether the line in listen() is the last line of the file.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can check if the current chunk of data is the last one.
You can only pass a callback that is called when the stream is closed.

```dart
Stream<List<int>> stream = new File('main.dart').openRead();
  stream.
  .transform(UTF8.decoder)
  .transform(const LineSpilitter())
  .listen((line) {
// TODO: check if this is the last line of the file
    var isLastLine;
  }
  ,onDone: (x) => print('done')); // <= add a second callback
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When parsing a text file, I need a way to treat the last segment differently than before. I cannot use onDone since it is all "done" streaming so text in variable 'line' is no longer available.

Comment: I understand. What you could do is to buffer the last line and only process it after you received the next line. `onDone` you process the last buffered line.

Comment: I think that could work. If I have to do this without a workaround, I might need to directly deal with byte from File without using Stream.

Answer (score 4):

While the answer from @Günter Zöchbauer works, the `last` property of streams accomplishes exactly what you are asking for (I guess the dart team added this functionality in the last 5 years).

```
Stream<List<int>> stream = new File('main.dart').openRead();
List<int> last = await stream.last;
```

**But note:** It is not possible to listen to the stream and use `await stream.last`.

This will cause an error:

> StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)

Comment: will this work if I use a broadcast stream that allows multiple listeners? Listening to each element and blocking code execution with await until the last event is received for beautiful code instead of having to work with callbacks.

Comment: not sure, but let me know if you figure this out 

Comment: instead of using .listen() on a stream I can simply use "await for" which does what I want: see this answer in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613676/8801473