# What difference between await for(var msg in receivePort) and receivePort.listen()?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am learning Dart:

```
main() async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawn(echo, receivePort.sendPort);

  // await for(var msg in receivePort)
  // {
  //   print(msg);
  // }

  receivePort.listen((msg) { print(msg);} ); 
}

echo(SendPort sendPort) async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send("message");
}
```

I can't understand when it's better to use `await for(var msg in receivePort)` and when `receivePort.listen()`? By the first look it's doing same. Or not?

Comment: `listen` (via the returned `StreamSubscription`) allows you to cancel the subscription. With `await for`, the only way to stop is for the `Stream` to emit an event that makes the loop exit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between await for and listen in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611880/difference-between-await-for-and-listen-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

I can say it is not the same. There is difference with `listen` and `await for`. `listen` just registers the handler and the execution continues.  And the `await for` hold execution till stream is closed.

If you would add a line `print('Hello World')` after  listen/await for lines,
You will see Hello world while using listen.

```
Hello World
message
```

because execution continues after that. But with await for,

There will be no hello world until stream closed.

```
import 'dart:isolate';

main() async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawn(echo, receivePort.sendPort);

  // await for(var msg in receivePort)
  // {
  //   print(msg);
  // }

  receivePort.listen((msg) { print(msg);} );
  print('Hello World');

}

echo(SendPort sendPort) async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send("message");
}
```