# How to close receivePort to get .toList() method working?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am trying to get answer from Isolate as list. I wrote next code. The problem That it's not working. It's simply wait.

```
main() async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawn(echo, receivePort.sendPort);

  var d = await receivePort.toList();
  receivePort.close();
  print(d);
}

echo(SendPort sendPort) async
{
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send("message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `receivePort` is a stream. When you call `toList` on the stream, it waits for the stream to complete. That never happens, so the `toList` call stalls forever.

If you know that the other end of the communication only sends one message, then you can instead do `var d = await receivePort.first;`. This only waits for the first message.

In general, when doing isolate communication, the sending isolate should send a special message when they are done, because the receiving isolate has no other way to know that. That is: You want a *communication protocol*, so the receiver can know whether there are going to be more messages. Maybe each message is an object which contains an `isLast` boolean, or the last message is `null`, or you wrap all messages in subclasses of a `Message` class that defines your protocol. What to do depends on the actual use-case.
The only rule is: You have to say when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *.listen()* instead of *await for*, if you want to see output of the list before is stream closed. listen will register the handler and execution keeps continue.

instead of

```
  var d = await receivePort.toList();
  receivePort.close();
  print(d);
```

try

```
receivePort.listen((data) => {print(data)});
```

You can find differences with listen and await [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004522/what-difference-between-await-forvar-msg-in-receiveport-and-receiveport-listen/57473964#57473964)