# How does one (and should one?) cancel a stream from an await-for loop in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a question about Dart streams, as follows. When I use a Stream via its `listen()` method, I can assign the result returned by `listen` to a variable and cancel the Subscription when I'm done (such as a `dispose()` method). How should I go about canceling a Stream listened by an `await-for` loop?

Just to clarify, I am not looking to change the flow of execution (as in, to cancel the Stream so that the code after the `await-for` runs), but to prevent memory leaks when I don't need the Stream anymore.

Answer (score 8):

The one and only way to cancel the subscription created by an `await for` is to exit the loop.

The moment you leave the loop using a control flow operation like `return`, `break`, `continue`, `throw` or `rethrow` (or a `yield` operation in an `async*` function where the listener on the stream has cancelled), the `cancel` method on the underlying subscription is automatically cancelled.

If the loop terminates itself, then it is because the stream is already done, so there is nothing to worry about.

If you want to keep computing inside the loop for a long time, and then exit the loop, then I recommend restructuring the code to do the computation outside of the loop instead. That is:

```
await for (var event in stream) {
  if (event.isTheOne) {
    await longComputation(event);
    break;
  }
}
```

will keep the stream alive and paused until `longComputation` completes.
instead I'd do something like:

```
var theOne = null;
await for (var event in stream) {
  if (event.isTheOne) {
    theOne = event; 
    break; 
  }
}
if (theOne != null) await longComputation(theOne);
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think `How should I go about canceling a Stream` is a bit misspelled. In case of `listen` method you have properly written `cancel the Subscription`, because you cancel subscription, not a steam itself.

`listen()` is non-blocking, it creates a subscription, registers a callback and then continues to execute the next code in the current block of code. The `await for` construct is **blocking**, it does not create a subscription to the stream. The execution of code will not go beyond the `await for` scope until the stream is closed. It is described with examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611880/difference-between-await-for-and-listen-in-dart). So per my understanding you don't need to worry about memory leaks in case of `await for`.