# Async await not behaving properly

Tags: dart

Trying to figure out why this does not execute in the order I'm expecting it to. I'm expecting 2 to be the last to execute but it's completing before everything else finishes running.
Can't understand why it's returning the function after 4 and before listening to the stream.

```
Future mainFn() async {
    print('Listen 1');
    Ob o = await listenFn();
    print('Listen 2');
    return await someFn(o);
  }

Future<Ob> listenFn() async {
    o = new Ob();
    print('Listen 3');
    Stream<Ct> stream = await getCt();
    print('Listen 4');
    stream.listen((Ct _ct) {
      print('Listen 7');
      if (!cts.contains(_ct)) {
        setState(() {
          cts.add(_ct);
        });
      }
    }, onError: (a) {
      print('Listen 8');
      print(a);
    }, onDone: () async {
      print('Listen 9');
      o = await addOb(cts); <-- This function returns Future<Ob>
    });
  await stream.drain();
  print('Listen 14');
  return o;
  }

Future<Stream<Ct>> getCt() async {
  print('Listen 5');
  final String url = 'API_URL';
  final client = new http.Client();
  final request = http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url));
  final streamedRest = await client.send(request);
  print('Listen 6');
  return streamedRest.stream
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .transform(json.decoder)
      .map((data) => Helper.getData(data))
      .expand((data) => (data as List))
      .map((data) {
    return Ct.fromJSON(data);
  });
}
```

I'm getting

```
I/flutter (22211): Listen 1
I/flutter (22211): Listen 3
I/flutter (22211): Listen 5
I/flutter (22211): Listen 6
I/flutter (22211): Listen 4
I/flutter (22211): Listen 2
I/flutter (22211): Listen 7 <-- 4 Ct items in the stream
I/flutter (22211): Listen 7
I/flutter (22211): Listen 7
I/flutter (22211): Listen 7
I/flutter (22211): Listen 9
I/flutter (22211): Listen 10 <-- added more of these along the way
I/flutter (22211): Listen 11
I/flutter (22211): Listen 12
I/flutter (22211): Listen 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone stumbles upon this in the future, I've chanced upon a solution to this. The answer is to use `await for`.

stream.listen() sets up code that will be put on the event queue when an event arrives, then following code is executed.

await for suspends between events and keeps doing so until the stream is done, so code following it will not be executed until that happens.

```
await for(String s in stream) { print(s); }
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613676/12689749

Answer (score 1):

Here's a breakdown:

1. Enter `mainFn`, prints `Listen 1`.
2. `mainFn` calls and awaits `listenFn`.
3. Enter `listenFn`.  Prints `Listen 3`.
4. `listenFn` calls and awaits `getCt`.
5. Enter `getCt`.  Prints `Listen 5`.
6. `getCt` calls and awaits `client.send`.
7. `client.send` does its work and returns.
8. `getCt` resumes and prints `Listen 6`.
9. `getCt` returns a `Stream`.
10. `listenFn` resumes and prints `Listen 4`.
11. `listenFn` adds a listener to the `Stream`.
12. `listenFn` **returns nothing**.
13. `mainFn` resumes and prints `Listen 2`.
14. `mainFn` calls and await `someFn`.
15. The `Stream` emits events, triggering the listener callback.
16. The listener callback prints `Listen 7` for each event.
17. The `Stream` eventually completes and prints `Listen 9`.

Where you go wrong is that you expect that `listenFn` will return the result of the `onDone` callback.  `listenFn` does not wait for the `Stream` to run to completion; it registers a callback and returns immediately.  If you run `dartanalyzer` on your code, you should get a warning mentioning that `listenFn` is declared to return a value but never returns anything.

Comment: This makes sense now. How would I make it wait for stream.listen? Adding await stream.listen does nothing.

Comment: `Stream.listen` just registers callbacks, which happens synchronously.  There is nothing to wait for, so it does not return a `Future`.  You must wait for the `Stream` itself to complete.  There are a number of ways you could do that, but the most appropriate is probably `await stream.drain();`.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and exactly what I was looking for. await stream.drain seems to be doing the trick holding back the return. But now everything after that line does not execute even as the onDone function is executed.

Comment: Are you saying that `Listen 2` is not printed?  It sounds like you're waiting on a `Future` that never completes.  Note that you still need to fix the problem that `listenFn` isn't returning the value you intend (which you attempt to do from `onDone`, but the `onDone` callback cannot return a value).

Comment: I added a line between await.drain and the return that never gets printed. ```await stream.drain();
    print('Listen 14');
    return o; ``` And Listen 2 is missing as well. I placed this in the main function outside the onDone brackets.

Comment: I made the edit above. I declared a new Ob o at the start so there's no reason why it wouldn't return o except if listen.drain never releases.

Comment: I've tried creating a StreamSubscription for stream.listen() and calling subscription.cancel() within onDone but it's not working either

Comment: Your `onDone` callback is still not quite right since `o` will be assigned at some indeterminate point in the future, likely after `listenFn` attempts to return it.  I'm not sure that you actually need the `onDone` callback; can't you move all of that to be done after `await stream.drain()`?  Otherwise, I don't know what else is wrong.  You should try to create a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: The onDone was there so that the function waited for the stream to finish looping through the objects. I moved everything to under await stream.drain() but everything below does not trigger. I even left subscription.cancel() in the onDone function and the line after that function prints. Something isn't releasing stream.drain()