# Listen for Future's List items

Tags: dart

I have got `Future<List<Directory>> dave`. `dave` is a Future, but in the future it might change into a Stream. Therefore I think ahead and subscribe to him like this:

```
var daveSub = Stream<List<Directory>>
    .fromFuture(dave())
    .listen((List<Directory> folders) {
  ...
});
```

If `dave` gives me a directory with path under some `/root/folder`, I want to `doStuff();` and cancel my subscription to `dave`. My current approach looks like this:

```
var daveSub = Stream<List<Directory>>
    .fromFuture(dave())
    .listen((List<Directory> folders) {

  for (final Directory folder in folders) {
    if (folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder')) {
      doStuff(folder);
      daveSub.cancel();
    }
  }

});
```

But this doesn't look right to me, especially the for cycle inside listener. Using a basic features of Future it doesn't look right as well:

```
dave()
    .then((List<Directory> folders) {

  for (final Directory folder in folders) {
    if (folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder')) {
      doStuff(folder);
    }
  }

});
```

**Is there some better way to handle `dave`'s list items (and maybe avoid the nested for cycle)?**

I would expect something like this:

```
Stream<Directory>
    .fromFuture(dave())
    .firstItemWhere((Directory folder) => folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder'))
    .then((Directory folder) {
  doStuff(folder);
});
```

or this:

```
dave()
    .firstItemWhere(((Directory folder) => folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder')) {
  doStuff(folder);
});
```

or at least:

```
dave()
    .then((List<Directory> folders) {
  for (final Directory folder in folders if folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder')) {
    doStuff(folder);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611880/difference-between-await-for-and-listen-in-dart ?

Comment: I know about this, but I'm not sure how it could help me to make things better in this case

Comment: Toy may want to change the `Stream<List<X>>` to a `Stream<X>`, perhaps by `var stream = future.asStream().expand((x)=>x);`. Then you get one element at a type instead of just one list of the elements.

Then the `firstWhere` should work.

Comment: Cool! Is it a good strategy to use expand() ?

Comment: Does expand have any advantage over for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lrn suggested, `expand()` is what I was looking for. Similar stream then looks like this:

```
Stream<List<Directory>>.fromFuture(dave())
                .expand((List<Directory> _folders) => _folders)
                .listen((Directory _folder) {
                  doStuff();
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a break clause to exit your loop when you find the right one:

```dart
var daveSub = Stream<List<Directory>>
    .fromFuture(dave())
    .listen((List<Directory> folders) {

  for (final Directory folder in folders) {
    if (folder.path.startsWith('/root/folder')) {
      doStuff(folder);
      break;
    }
  }
   daveSub.cancel();

});
```

What is wrong with the loop inside the listener?

Comment: I compeltely forgot about `break`, that is much better than cancelling a subscription or iterating full Future result!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept answer if you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to find the item you are looking for without even having to handle a subscription, take a look at this example:

```
void main() async {
 var stream = Stream.fromIterable([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
  var item = await stream.expand((e) => e)
               .firstWhere((e) => e == 3, orElse: () => null);
  
  if (item != null) {
     // Do stuff 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I insert Future<List<Directory>> into Future.value() ?

Comment: You can insert whatever type you want, that was just an example and btw using either `Future.asStream` or `Stream.fromFuture` has no difference afaik

Comment: It doesn't work for me, your example returns me the whole List, not a single item

Comment: You must have an error in your code, please share what you have done.

Comment: I copied your code and inserted print(item); into the if. I found out there is no `e` because the only `e` it got is `[1,2,3,4,5]` which is != 3. Also the only item I could get was `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: I'm sorry, now it should work properly, I edited the code to better reflect your structure. Please try it out

Comment: Now it's just the same as @lrm mentioned above. Anyway it sums what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does expand have any advantage over for loop?